# Jenkins agent on windows auto reconnection failing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I tried connecting my windows agent in cmd with this command and it was able to connect.

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl <my ip>jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret <my secret> -workDir "C:\jenkins
```

but if i try running it through batch file in order to avoid manual connection each time i restart the system it was not able to connect. below is the error

```
Failed to obtain http://***********/computer/windows0slave0node/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true
java.io.IOException Failed to load http://************/computer/windows0slave0node/jenkins-agent.jnlp?encrypt=true: 404 Not Found
  
Waiting 10 seconds before retry
```

My requirement is whenever I reboot my ec2 instance where the agent runsit must be automatically connected with the jenkins controller without connecting it remotely

am using windows ec2 instance.

Comment: Please add content of your batch file to the question. It is propably missing escaping of special batch characters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you should check if jnlpUrl has '%5F' and replace it with '_' , e.g
`java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://<host>/computer/windows%5Fslave%5Fagent/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret -workDir`
change to 
`http://<host>/computer/windows_slave_agent/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret -workDir`